# wait until Sheet is closed in blackberry 10

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I am currently working a bb10 app.

I have QML document `main.qml`. It contains a button.

On the click of the button I am calling a function `HandleClickEvent()`.

Inside `HandleClickEvent()` I am calling a function `DisplaySheet()`.

and Immediately after `DisplaySheet()` function call I am calling another function `GetData()` inside `HandleClickEvent()`

Inside `DisplaySheet()` function I am creating the complete UI of the Sheet and displaying it.
User will be able to close it using a button present in the sheet.

I want that the function `GetData()` should be called only after the sheet has been closed not before that. Right now it getting called right after the call of function `DisplaySheet()`

How can I enable this in my app.

Comment: You are probably assuming that your DisplaySheet() would block until the sheet is closed, unfortunately it is not that simple.

Comment: yeah I know that, but I want to know how it can be accomplished

Answer (score 3):

Study [signal slot mechanism](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/signals_slots/), it will serve your purpose.

Sheet has closed signal, connect that signal with your GetData() function

```
QObject::connect(obejctOfSheet, SIGNAL(closed()), objectContainingYourFunction, SLOT(GetData()));
```

Comment: In the function `HandleClickEvent()` I don't have the sheet object with me. it is created and opened inside the function `DisplaySheet()` only

Comment: You can connect signal/slot in DisplaySheet method. Share your code in question for better understanding.